# Can the new Eevee Renderer render Freestyle lines?

Tags: materials, freestyle, eevee-render-engine

And can it render using the Toon BSDF? I've heard people claim it can use the same shaders as Cycles, and i'd like to know if that's true.

Comment: Freestyle is a completely separate stroke and fill rendering engine, it is in theory mostly independent from the underlying regular shaded engine. It could theoretically be used along with EEVVEE, but weather it actually will or not is unknown at this point even for developers I think. There may or may not be plans for a different OpenGL based solution, it is a guess at this point

Comment: Cool, so has anyone tried the Toon BSDF with it?